# Why are we so concerned about mistaking meat on Pesach?

Tags: halacha, passover, meat, korban

The Shulchan Aruch in siman 469 and 476 lays out the concerns we have that someone might mistake you main course for a real Korban Pesach. This includes not saying 'this meat is for Peasach' and not eating certain foods roasted. Some Achronim there extend these enactments even further, the details of which are not my concern here.

My question is why are we so concerned about mixing up the meat with a real Korban? To put it in perspective, we don't find an concern on Succos or Shvuos that one might think you are eating a Shlamim. So why here?

Comment: Because the Samaritains were (and are) still doing it? Combined with the fact that eating davka roasted meat is more rare (evidenced by the question about it in the Ma Nishtana).

Comment: @Yishai these are good points. I would at least +1 if you converted this to an answer. But on a side point, finding someone with a roasted sheep doesn't seem to be an issue of us suspecting him of Samaritan heresy. Its at worst a kodshim issue.

Comment: Just to add to Yishai's point, I know a Kaarite Jew, and he told me they do a Korban Pesach every year.

Comment: I'm not totally satisfied with those points to make an answer, especially when it is just speculation. Another point is that a Korban Pesach is Hutra B'Tuma, so there is more reason to think you brought one than a Shlamim.

Comment: @Yishai ah this last point is the one I think is the real answer. I was hoping someone would have a source for that though, hence my question.

Comment: @user6591 It might have something to do with the fact that Korban Pesach MUST be roasted, where as the other chagims seudahs can be cooked however they want.

Comment: @warz3 could be. But even so, it would only help with siman 476. Not 479.

Comment: @user6591 I think the pashtus is that the Korban Pesach is additional to the chagigah, and therefore if you say "lshem pesach" youre giving off the impression that the meat is actually the korban and its mutar to bring it up on bamos, as opposed to the chagigah which is separate and everyone knows is bitul since they're not also at the temple mount

Comment: @warz3 the bama point was raised in a previous comment. And you don't have to say lishem. Simply saying basar zeh lipesach is a problem. Think about that you are shopping and pick up a roast and say to the peraon standing next to you and say this is my pesach roast.

Comment: "Pesach" is the name of a Korban. If you bought meat for Sukkot and said "This is for Shalmei Simcha" that'd probably be a problem too.